# Facebook Connect Plugin and Grails Issue

Tags: grails, facebook, grails-plugin

Not sure how to begin troubleshooting this issue. I followed the exact instructions on this page - http://www.grails.org/Facebook+Connect+Plugin
Are the instructions on this page correct? or missing something?
Is this plugin abandoned for something else? Not sure where Spring Social fits into this, or if that is even production-ready.

`Error 500: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:facebookConnectJavascript>: Error creating bean with name 'FacebookTagLib': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'facebookConnectService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FacebookConnectConfig at P:/testapp/grails-app/views/loginFacebook/auth.gsp:15
Servlet: grails
URI: /lmfirst/grails/loginFacebook/auth.dispatch
Exception Message: FacebookConnectConfig
Caused by: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:facebookConnectJavascript>: Error creating bean with name 'FacebookTagLib': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'facebookConnectService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FacebookConnectConfig at P:/testapp/grails-app/views/loginFacebook/auth.gsp:15
Class: FacebookConnectService
At Line: [15]
Code Snippet:`

**MORE INFORMATION:**
Groovy Version: 1.7.5 JVM: 1.6.0_22
Grails 1.3.7
Can anyone else replicate this issue with the plugin? and the example code?

Comment: I put the code I am using (same as ref link) on pastebin here http://pastebin.com/au2Pwjy5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the plugin. I faced the same problem now. This is a temporary work around:
Go to FacebookConnectService and modify the afterPropertiesSet() method like this:

```
void afterPropertiesSet() {
    def config
    try {
        config = Class.forName("FacebookConnectConfig").newInstance()
        facebookConnectConfig = new ConfigSlurper().parse(config.getClass()) 
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) { 
        // no compiled class exists for the config, we must be running the Grails built-in web server 
        GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()) 
        Class clazz = loader.parseClass(new File("grails-app/conf/FacebookConnectConfig.groovy")) 
        facebookConnectConfig = new ConfigSlurper().parse(clazz) 
    }
}
```

Comment: I raised a JIRA issue for the same: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPFACEBOOKCONNECT-6

Comment: I switched to using the Faceboog Graph plugin instead: http://www.grails.org/plugin/facebook-graph

Comment: Finally ran into the JIRA last night. Think I might switch to the Facebook-Graph plugin too. Seems like they should flag the "Connect" plugin as abandoned. Did it work for you in jetty? and not tomcat? Didn't work for me at all.

Comment: I just tried in jetty and it didn't work. Once I found this problem, I had a look at facebook-graph and it was doing what I wanted without any problem, so I switched to using it :)

Comment: Thanks. Think you might also be able to answer this one too since you have experience with Facebook API - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125145/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

From the error output it seems you're missing the back slash **/** at the end of the tag.

```
<g:facebookConnectJavascript  />
```

Start there.. and post the results.

Comment: That would be weird because I cut and pasted the code. Backslash was there. Tried it out in 2 different grails apps with the same result.

Comment: See the first comment to question.